# Angular 5 - Passing data from parent to component by way of service or output sends the entire list

Tags: angular, angular5

Okay, there are the components involved here:
assignment-list-component
add-assignment-button
add-assignment-popover

My parent component is displaying a list of assignments in an NgFor and for every table row there is a childcomponent 'add-assignment-button' with a click event on it.

If its clicked my parent component passes the entire assignment (NOT PLURAL) to a service where add-assignment-popover can subscribe on it. The problem is, it sends the entire list. I dont know how to make the click event specific. Tried with index on every button, but that does nothing.

**EDIT:** I want to clarify two things. 
No1: I have tried with @Input in add-contact-popover, I get the same result. 
No2: When I say the entire list, I mean every assignment one-by-one gets sent. When I console log, (if I have five assignments in the list) there will be five console logs (console log 1 has the first assignment, and so on)..

**I only want the assignment (1, ONE) that belongs to the row where I click on the button.**

This is the parent component (In interest of time, I'll only show the relevant data)

```
@Component({
selector: 'assignment-list',
template: `
    <tr *ngFor="let assignment of assignmentList">
            <td class="actions">
                <add-contact-button-component(click)="sendClickedRowDataToPopOver(assignment)"></add-contact-button-component>
                <add-assignment-contact-popover></add-assignment-contact-popover>
            </td>
    </tr>
`
})

export class AssignmentList implements OnInit {

  sendClickedRowDataToPopOver(assignment: AssignmentListItem) {
     this.tableRowDataService.sendAssignmentData(assignment);
   }
}
```

And this is the tablerowService

```
@Injectable()
export class TableRowDataService {
assignmentData = new EventEmitter<AssignmentListItem>();

sendAssignmentData(assignmentObject: AssignmentListItem) {
    this.assignmentData.emit(assignmentObject);
   }
}
```

Finally here is the popover

```
    ngOnInit() {
    this.resetValues();

    //Clickservice for knowing when createbutton is pushed.
    this.buttonClickService.showAddContactPopOver.subscribe((addContactCLick: boolean) => {
        if (addContactCLick) {

            this.tableRowDataService.assignmentData.subscribe(
                (assignmentObj: AssignmentListItem) => {
                    this.addValuesToPopover(assignmentObj);
                });
        }
    });
}

addValuesToPopover(assignmentObject: AssignmentListItem) {
    console.log('assignmentObject', assignmentObject);
}
```

Edit: Here is the contact button.

```
@Component({
selector: 'add-contact-button-component',
template: `
<a class="assignment-add-dependent-link lnk"
  title="add new contact"
  (click)="addButton()"
   [routerLink]="" 
  style="margin-right: 6px;">
   <i class="icon-plus blue"></i>
    <span>New Contact</span>
 </a>
`
 })

export class AddContactButtonComponent {

addClick = false;

constructor(private buttonClickService: ButtonClickService) { }

addButton() {
    this.addClick = !this.addClick;
    this.buttonClickService.showAddContactPopOver.next(this.addClick);
   }

}
```

Comment: Can you also share contact-button-component codes? There might be something wrong when you handle the click event in that component. Also I'm not sure, why you want to use EventEmitter in your service. Is there any specific reason for that?

Comment: Im learning, this is my first project with angular, it saw that you could use EventEmitter, so why not? Is it not optimal? Everything works in the sense that I get the data, its just that I get the entire list, not just the clicked object...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't attachment click event to the Angular Component. Instead, you can send the object as input to the Component. From Child Component, you can call services and instead of using EventEmitter(), you should use Subject.

Mainly EventEmitter will be used if you want to share data from Child to Parent Component.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ukupfj

Comment: Well, yes. This is what I tried at first. I followed this stackblitz from a stackthread: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jbofnk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts

Comment: I added [dataFromParent]="assignment" to the add-contact-popover in the assignment-list.html and then I had the input dataFromParent in the add-contact-popover component but it was the same= the entire list was sent when I clicked on one of the buttons..

Comment: But I can change it back, if that is the convention.

Comment: Created Stackblitz and updated the communication Flow

Comment: This was how I did. But only the the lines I wrote in the above comment. I didnt send anything to the parent, I only have Input dataFromParent on add-contact-popover that I send to a function which console logs it,  and [dataFromParent]="assignment" on the add-contact-popover component on the assignment-list html. When I click on the add-contact-button It shows all five assignments separately, in each consolelogs almost as if I click on all five buttons at the same time. Could It be because the assignments dont have IDs?

Comment: Basically your stackblitz does the same thing: It sends all three objects from the list to the childcomponent. I only want the one I click on.

Comment: Updated Stackblitz now. Check it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Input , @Output decorators which are created for handling this kind of data sharing and component interaction.

Ref: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: Well, yes. This is what I tried at first. I followed this stackblitz from a stackthread: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jbofnk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts

Comment: I added [dataFromParent]="assignment" to the add-contact-popover in the assignment-list.html and then I had the input dataFromParent in the add-contact-popover component but it was the same= the entire list was sent when I clicked on one of the buttons..

Comment: But I can change it back, if that is the convention.

Comment: It seems @SureshKumarAriya fixed it. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ukupfj . (Y)